# Eager-Loading based on the first query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eager-loading

> Query where the problem lies

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();

$place = Place::near($user)->with(['services','services.registrable' => function (MorphTo $query) {
            $query->where('distance_of_visibility', '<', \DB::raw('places.distance'));
        }])->find(22);

\DB::disableQueryLog();
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

> Generated queries

First: The queries will calculate all the places in a given radius and add the calculated field **distance** to the select

```
 select *, st_distance_sphere(`location`, ST_GeomFromText(0.000000 00.000000)) as distance from `places` where st_distance_sphere(`location`, ST_GeomFromText(0.000000 00.000000)) <= 5000 and `places`.`id` = 22 limit 1
```

Second: `with` will eager-load the `services`

```
select * from `services` where `services`.`place_id` in (22)
```

Finally: `with` will try to load `registrable` but the eager-load gives **an obvious error since places.distance doesn't exist in this scope**

```
select * from information where distance_of_visibility < places.distance and information.id in (5)
```

which throw

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'places.distance' in 'where clause'
```

> What am I trying to do

Let's say the calculated field **distance** of a **place** returns the value **55** meters

I want to eager load the information (through the services) only when the **distance_of_visibility** is under those **55** meters.

**So my question is**: how can I make it work in the most efficient way. Calculate the distance take some querying time. I would try to avoid join table + recalculation. I guess there's a way to access to the previous queries results from `$query` but I couldn't figure how.

> Context in case you need more information

**Place Model**
 1. It uses https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial
 2. Is `hasMany` **Service**
 3. It contain a scope that add the calculated field **distance** to the select:

```
    /**
     * Get the places near the user in a certain radius
     * It also add the distance in the select statement 
     *
     * @param SpatialBuilder $query
     * @param Geolocalisable $geolocalisable
     * @return SpatialBuilder
     */
    public function scopeNear(SpatialBuilder $query, Geolocalisable $geolocalisable): SpatialBuilder
    {
        return $query
            ->distanceSphereValue('location', $geolocalisable->position())
            ->distanceSphere('location', $geolocalisable->position(), $geolocalisable->radiusInMeter());
    }
```

**Service Model**
 1. The **Service** `belongsTo` a **Place**
 2. The **Service** `MorphTo` a **Registrable**

**Registrable Model**
1. There's no **Registrable** Model. It's a polymorphic relationship with multiple Models. In this example, you're seeing "Information"
2. Those **Registrable** Models `morphOne` **Service**

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by a "calculated field"? Additionally, please add the "obvious error" with the full and exact error message to your question

Comment: Is it more understandable? English isn't my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're asking to do isn't possible with Eloquent.

The eager-load query is entirely separate from the initial query so any values retrieved are no longer available.

Your options are either to do a join in your constraint (which you indicated might not be performant), or load all the related models and then sort/filter those using PHP instead.