# How to get pivot data inside eloquent withCount function callback?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use a pivot variable of a parent relationship inside the eloquent `withCount()` method.

Background:

There is a application with a ManyToMany relationship between Users and Clusters. Users can send messages within a cluster. To keep track of the unread message count for a user in a specific cluster i keep track of the last read message id in the join table, like so:

```
table: cluster_user

cluster_id | user_id | last_read_message_id
-------------------------------------------
 1         | 59      | 3
 2         | 62      | 8
```

- The `User()` model has a `belongsToMany()` relation with the `Cluster()` model
- The `Cluster()` model has a `belongsToMany()` relation with the `User()` model
- The `Cluster()` model has a `hasMany()` relation with the `Messages()` model
- The `Message()` model has a `belongsTo()` relation with the `Cluster()` model

Now I would like to list all the clusters of the authenticated user including a unread message count.

Currently I'm stuck on this:

```
$clusters = Auth::user()->clusters()->withCount(['messages' => function ($query) {
  $query->where('messages.id', '>', '???');
}])->get();
```

I've already tried:

```
$clusters = Auth::user()->clusters()->withCount(['messages' => function ($query) {
  $query->where('messages.id', '>', 'cluster_user.last_read_message_id');
}])->get();
```

But this gives me a total count of all the messages in stead of the ones with an id higher than x.
If I hardcode an id, like this:

```
$clusters = Auth::user()->clusters()->withCount(['messages' => function ($query) {
  $query->where('messages.id', '>', '3');
}])->get();
```

Then I get the correct unread message count.

So can somebody tell me how to use the pivot variable 'last_read_message_id' of the `user()->cluster()` relationship inside the `withCount()` callback function with the following in mind:

- I'ts crucial to use as little queries as possible.
- The unread message count must be a part of the cluster() collection because I'm returning a `ClusterResource` later on, like so:

`return ClusterResource::collection($clusters);`

which includes the unread message count.

```
class ClusterResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'unread_messages_count' => $this->whenPivotLoaded('cluster_user', $this->messages_count)
        ];
    }
}
```

Thnx!

Comment: I got the basically the same question yesterday and the answer was, you can't.. :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444858/eager-loading-based-on-the-first-query In case you find a way, I would still be interested.

Comment: @cbaconnier interesting! and sad :( Although when i output a `getQueryLog()` i get the following query: `select 'clusters'.*, (select count(*) from 'messages' where 'clusters'.'id' = 'messages'.'cluster_id' and 'messages'.'id' > ?) as 'messages_count', blablabla from 'clusters' inner join 'cluster_user' on 'clusters'.'id' = 'cluster_user'.'cluster_id' where 'cluster_user'.'user_id' = ?` (replaced a piece with blablabla to shorten it). If I replace  the first question mark with `cluster_user`.`last_read_message_id` the result is correct, so it doesn't seem to be entirely seperate in this case!

Comment: @cbaconnier found the solution due to your comment! DB::raw('cluster_user.last_read_message_id') is working for me.

Comment: Hooooo! I'm happy for you then :)

Comment: i'll have a look at your question too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer due to a comment of @cbaconnier.

Placing `DB::raw('cluster_user.last_read_message_id')` on the spot is working. I't not neat, but it works.

Full example:

```
$clusters = Auth::user()
     ->clusters()
     ->withCount(['messages' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('messages.id', '>', DB::raw('cluster_user.last_read_message_id'));
     }])
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question! I think you should be able to do use the `withPivot` method on your relationship and then use the `pivot` attribute in your query.

For example, in your `Cluster` model where you define the `cluster_user` relationship, do:

```
function cluster_user() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
                ->withPivot('last_read_message_id');
}
```

And then in your query you could use `whereColumn` to compare the columns. Something like this:

```
$clusters = Auth::user()
    ->clusters()
    ->withCount(['messages' => function ($query) {
       $query->whereColumn('messages.id', '>',  
                           'pivot.last_read_message_id');
     }])
    ->get();
```

Search for "Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns" on the [Eloquent relationships documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for more information.

Comment: Thnx @Delena Malan for your answer, but the relation in the `Cluster` model is already declared like this:
`return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('last_read_message_id');`

Comment: Ah, yes, I just realised that it would take the value as `pivot.last_read_message_id` instead of the actual column value. You could play around with `whereColumn`. It should work similar to `DB::raw`.